# How to check Node session cookie expiration from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, backbone.js, node.js-connect

We're using Node + Connect to manage sessions for our app, which is a single-page application (SPA) built with Backbone.js.  I'm trying to write some code which will check from the client if the session is still valid.  I know I can do it in Node itself, but as this is an SPA, I need to be able to do it completely client-side.

My first thought was to read the *connect.sid* cookie with jQuery and if it wasn't there, then that would mean that the session is expired.  Unfortunately, that session cookie is protected with the **HttpOnly** flag and for good reason.  I don't want to disable that.

My second thought was to write a *second, parallel* cookie every time the *connect.sid* cookie is written.  This second cookie would only store the expire date of the session cookie and would set **HttpOnly** to false so that the client could read it.

> So my question is, how do I go about writing that second cookie, ***or*** is there a better solution for being able to detect session expiration status from the browser?
>
> I know how to write cookies with Node, but I'm not sure where to put the code so that it will fire every time that Connect writes the main *connect.sid* session cookie.  Additionally, I would like to be to read the expire date of the session cookie so that I can write it in my parallel cookie.

UPDATE: To be clear, I'm not looking to read the expiration date of the session.  I know that JS cannot access the expires date of a cookie.  I just want to see whether or not the cookie exists, as it will only exist when it's valid and therefore its absence is enough data for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated after clarifications in comments**

Add another middleware right next to your session middleware. Excerpt below assumes express, but if you are using connect without express you should be able to interpret accordingly.

```
app.use(connect.session(sessionOptions));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.cookie("sessionIsAlive", "1", {
     //just make sure this matches your expiration time of the real session cookie
     expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000),
     httpOnly: false
  });
  next();
});
```

Then you can check for the existence of that via javascript in the browser. And just FYI connect writes a new cookie with an updated expiration time on every response. That's how the "expires after N minutes of inactivity" behavior is implemented.

Comment: As mentioned, I need a client-side solution, as opposed to _res.cookie()_ which is a server-side solution.  As for manually writing cookies, I can handle that part well enough but what I don't know is where I can hook in that code so that it writes that second cookie all the places where Node would write the session cookie.

Comment: No, your question asks how you go about setting that second cookie, which you do on the server side with `httpOnly` false and then you check for its existence in the browser.

Comment: Ok, sorry if I wasn't more clear.  I know how to write cookies with Node, that part is easy.  What I don't know is where to go about putting that code such that it fires every time that Connect tries to write the _connect.sid_ session cookie.

Comment: Peter, thanks a bunch.  I'll try that out and get back to you.